# Setup gradle for a network user directory

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, gradle

I've been having some issues with gradle, because until now I wasn't able to set it up properly. I have my user directory as a network drive (company policy) and it's only available while I am connected, but I would also like to be able to make gradle work offline. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance for any help.

### UPDATE

There is a good explanation to customize the user home for gradle and Android Studio on [tools.android.com](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration).

Answer (score 0):

Gradle stores some information in the users home directory. You can try to set another directory with the `-g, --gradle-user-home` option.

Comment: I've tried that. But I get an exception:
 `A problem occurred evaluating project ':MyProject'
> Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'.`

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some inconsistency around -g gradle command line option.

You may try setting `GRADLE_USER_HOME=/the/path/you/want` environment variable to point for some local drive directory.

Another thing worth trying is running gradle command with option `-Dgradle.user.home=/the/path/you/want`

I believe the same effect should be achievable with adding the line `gradle.user.home=/the/path/you/want` to gradle.properties on the root directory of your project. I'm not sure about this one though.

OH, I see among your tags 'intellij-idea'. There is [a bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-116684) and idea seems to ignore all the above settings when you try to use gradle wrapper with it.

However when local gradle installation is used, I may confirm that setting env variable GRADLE_USER_HOME works *almost* fine. All caches, downloaded artifacts and so on will go to specified dir, but Idea still tends to create .gradle dir in the user home (on network drive) and creates a few files related to gradle daemon process.
I'm struggling with the same issue recently and even have tried Idea 13.1 EAP. Issues still exists though.

Another thing, don't try using Gradle 1.11 or above with Idea. There is [another bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-119755) which makes it impossible.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've tried all and I got it working with the local installation, although I still have some problems from time to time.

Comment: Always glad to help. You may consider upvoting the bug on Jetbrains youtrack.